# What exactly are Quest bikes?

Tags: identify-this-bike

My wife has about 10-15 years old, but very rarely used (thus in quite good condition) bike with a large "Quest" label in place, where all other bikes has its brand name.

By reading all the labels on that bike, I managed to read this:

> Quest Courage, 20 inch, 21 level Shimano, Quest Courier

Not much, but I thought, that using Google etc. this will allow me to learn more about these bikes. However, when I tried to search the Internet, I found very little toward nothing. All I found was [this site](https://www.abikecalledquest.com/?___store=en&___from_store=de), but it seems to be about completely different product.

On some old forum there was a post claiming, that this is a marketing name for Dick's Sporting Goods, but [searching this site for `Quest` name brought no results around bikes](http://www.dickssportinggoods.com/search/index.jsp?kwCatId=&kw=quest&origkw=Quest&sr=1).

I also read a few claims, that this is a very, very low-end and very low quality line of products. Some even said, that if you plan to ride more than 10 miles on road or take this bike off-road then you should definitely forget about "Quest" line.

All these claims seems to be contrary to what I have and to what many bicycle repair shops claimed about my wife's bike (saying, that it looks like a good quality and in good condition, taking its age).

Can someone shed a light, what exactly is this brand? Is it still in production or when it was produced, if it is off market right know? Is there any website or support or anything?

Comment: There are likely thousands of bike "brands" that have been use over the years.  Especially with the Chinese churning out cheap bikes like they are there's a need by the manufacturers to change brand names frequently so that a poor quality reputation doesn't build up.  Don't know about "Quest" in particular, but many brands like this are only sold for a year or two, then they quietly go away.

Comment: Quest was a brand sold at Walmart and similar -- its what we call a BSO. DRH is right as usual.

Comment: In this case, I think that Daniel should form that comment as an answer, because I suppose, we're not going to come with anything more in details.

Comment: One might correctly assume that a low wear bike is more valuable than a hard-used bike, but the initial quality of the components is far more important.

Comment: If there's a label with "Shimano" and number of speeds on the frame, there's a good chance it's not a good bike. Shimano does manufacture some very good components, but those tend to be labeled with small "Shimano", larger component series label and never stickers on the frame.

Comment: "Is there any website or support or anything?" Almost all bicycle components are generic, so you don't need specialist manufacturer support, except for warranty issues on new bikes.

Comment: I've been riding my Quest bike for the past 10 years and really haven't had any issues with it. I usually put an average of 32 to 40 miles a week on the bicycle. I find it comfortable and durable.

Comment: I have obtained a donated 16" Quest Sea Starz with a label on the bottom: "LBH1618G 1-800-596-8224" The model number produced an import record from China in 2008. That phone was a consumer line but is now disconnected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quest was sold by Oshmans sporting goods in the 90s with mid range
 cro-moly frames and Shimano components.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange - thank you for the relevant answer.  Do you have any sort of evidence - a link or similar?  What is Oshmans ?  Was it an international, regional, or just a local shop?   Where in the world would one have found this store?     Feel free to use [edit] to add the additional information.

Comment: Oshmans was a [Houston-based sporting goods chain](http://web.archive.org/web/20041027203044/http://www.oshmans.com/corp/index.jsp?page=corp_archive) founded in 1919. It got bought out by The Sports Authority chain in the early 2000s, and then Sports Authority went bankrupt and Dick's Sporting Goods bought the Sports Authority assets. But apparently Quest was also sold at Dick's: https://www.bikeforums.net/recreational-family/525609-quest-bike-anyone-knows-about-brand.html